# What does the letter g in xliff:g stand for

Tags: android, xml

I'm curious to know what the letter g in the following tag stand for:

```
<string name="countdown">
    <xliff:g id="time" example="5 days>%1$s</xliff:g>until holiday
</string>
```

I've copied this tag from https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html#manage-strings

I tried googling it but was unable to find any answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The g stands for *generic group placeholder*. 
The required `id` attribute is used to reference the replaced code in the  file.
You can read more about it in the specification provided [here](https://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#g)

Answer (score 2):

g means

**Generic Group Placeholder**

for more see this doc

http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#g

https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xliff/faq.php